# can only concatenate list (not "str") to list - type error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working a a list updating program but when I run this code I get `can only concatenate list (not "str") to list` error. Here is my code:

```
A = 1
B = 2
C = 3
D = 4
E = 5

Acount = 1
Bcount = 1
Ccount = 1
Dcount = 1
Ecount = 1

ScoreA = 20

X = [A, B, C, D, E]
Y = [20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
Ave = input('Enter hours spent revising (1-5): ')
if Ave == '1':
    Score = input('Enter test score: ')
    Acount += 1
    ScoreA = Y[0:1] + Score #Error occurs here
    ScoreA = ScoreA / Acount
    Y.insert(0, ScoreA)
```

Any help is appreciated, even it is only minor. If down voting please explain why so I can improve questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The value ScoreA is being assigned a list splice. Then, you try to add "Score" to the list, but Score is a string. Therefore, you need to access the element by index in ScoreA and add it to Score, casted to an int:

```
Y = [20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
Score = input('Enter test score: ')
Acount += 1
ScoreA = Y[0:1][0] + int(Score) #Here, accessing the first value of Y, which is the only value
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Y[0:1]` is a list:

```
In [95]: Y = [1,2,3,4,5]

In [96]: Y[0:1]
Out[96]: [1]
```

It seems that you are trying to add `Score` to the first element in `Y`, i.e. `Y[0]`. So I'd do this:

```
In [97]: Score = 5

In [98]: Y[0] += Score

In [99]: Y[0]
Out[99]: 6
```

There is another problem with your code, namely that `input` returns a string, not an int/float which you seem to want. Therefore, I'd recommend you change `Score = input('Enter test score: ')` to `Score = float(input('Enter test score: '))`